# InDesign: text frames visible on PDF export

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

This is probably a very basic issue, but I can't figure out why these dots around the text boxes are visible on the exported PDF file. They are not even visible in the InDesign source file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, solved it myself. All boxes that have these visible frames have transparency flattening issues, after exporting it to pdf (adobe pdf preset earlier than 2005).

When I export it to .pdf 2008 it works well - no frames.